# cout string c++

Tags: c++, sintaxe

Tenho uma função `Show()` a qual percorre uma lista e deveria mostra-la na tela, porém não consigo concatenar o valor de uma lista com uma string.
Segue código:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX 5
typedef struct {
    string Nome;
    double Salario;
} Funcionario;

typedef struct {
    Funcionario Funcionarios[MAX];
    int Inicio, Fim;
} Lista;


void Show(Lista *Lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Lista->Fim; i++) {
        cout << "Func.: " << Lista->Funcionarios[i].Nome;
        cout << "Salário: " << Lista->Funcionarios[i].Salario;
    }
}
```

O problema está no

```
 cout << "Func.: " << Lista->Funcionarios[i].Nome;
```

onde não consigo fazer o `cout`.
Tenho o seguinte erro

> E0349 nenhum operador "<<" corresponde a esses operandos os tipos de operandos são: std::basic_ostream> << std::string

Comment: Fez a chamada `using namespace std;`? Caso não tenha feito, o teu `cout` deve ser `std::cout`.

Comment: Sim já havia feito.

Answer (score 2):

O problema estava na importação de uma das bibliotecas.

Troquei

```
#include <string.h>
```

por

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Os includes .h são do C, no C++ eles não levam a extensão do arquivo.

Comment: Inclua o código errado na pergunta, senão parece que a resposta não tem relação com a pergunta